# build.sbt error: value addRepositoryAuthentication is not a member of lmcoursier.CoursierConfiguration

Tags: playframework, sbt, coursier, playframework-2.8

I have my private Gitlab lib repository defined as follow:

**build.sbt**

```
scalaVersion := "2.13.13"
/*** Gitlab private lib repository configuration ****/
resolvers += "gitlab" at "https://my-gitlab-repo.fun"
val token = "token"

val auth:Authentication = Authentication(Seq(("Private-Token",token)))
csrConfiguration ~= (_.addRepositoryAuthentication("gitlab",auth))
updateClassifiers / csrConfiguration ~= (_.addRepositoryAuthentication("gitlab",auth))
```

all works fine with sbt version `1.7.2`. If I update to 1.7.3 and then run a build command, I get this error:

```
build.sbt error: overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
(user: String,password: String)lmcoursier.definitions.Authentication <and>
...
val auth:Authentication = Authentication(Seq(("Private-Token",token)))
^
sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

Ok, no problem, I updated the line:

```
from:
val auth:Authentication = Authentication(Seq(("Private-Token",token)))

to:
val auth:Authentication = Authentication("Private-Token",token)
```

Now I run again the build command and the error change in:

```
build.sbt:59: error: value addRepositoryAuthentication is not a member of lmcoursier.CoursierConfiguration
csrConfiguration ~= (_.addRepositoryAuthentication("gitlab",auth))
^
[error] Type error in expression
```

Ok, If `addRepositoryAuthentication` is not a member of `lmcoursier.CoursierConfiguration` anymore, which method should I use?

Comment: What's the goal of these settings? Never seen them before. Look's similar to [repository and credentials](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Proxy-Repositories.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved the issue changing the `build.sbt` configuration in this way:

```
val auth:Authentication = Authentication("Private-Token",tokens.head)
val vector = Vector(("gitlab", auth))
csrConfiguration ~= (_.withAuthenticationByRepositoryId(vector))
updateClassifiers / csrConfiguration ~= (_.withAuthenticationByRepositoryId(vector))
```